# MODX GetResources display unpub_date

Tags: modx, getresource

I'm working on a event-calender in a mulit-level website for bands and choirs. Each band has his own page (made by Collections). A sub-document is used for making an event-item. On the homepage all event-items are published. The TV's for the event-item in the homepage, are a part of the template of the sub-document. To display them in the calender-item I use GetReousces. 
All works fine except the unpub_date.

To keep the calender up-to-date, I want to use the unpub_date and display it also in the calender-item on the homepage.
In the Recourse call I added unpub_date to '&includeTV's'.
In my Tpl I use [[+unpub_date:strtotime:date=`%d-%m-%Y, %H:%M`]]. Just like the call for e.g. pagetitle.
The unpub_date won't show. If I leave out 'strotime....' a number is displayed in stead of the date.
If I leave out unpub_date at the &includeTV's, it makes no difference. 
Changing the dateformat, has no effect either.

I hope someone has an answer. Much appreciated!
Thnx
Leo

Answer (score 0):

unpub_date is not a TV - you don't have to include it in your getresource call.   unpub_date is also not populated by default - it is the date on which you want a resource to automatically unpublish itself.

If you want a calendar best way to go about it is to create a start and end date TV.

Comment: Thanks. I have made a TV 'end date'. But it would be nice if you could fill this TV by the unpub_date. Now you have fill in unpub_date and the TV 'end date'. Well there are a lot of things worse than that I suppose. :-)